# Conexão entre dois SGBD Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe alguma forma além do `Linked` para conectar dois SGBD ?

**Problema:**

Preciso utilizar as tabelas de outro banco que está em outro servidor com o `SQL SERVER` instalado.

*Meu servidor atual também é SQL Server;*

Answer (score 3):

Tem que criar um linkedServer entre os servidores. Através do Linked Server você cria um link de comunicação entre um servidor e outro desta forma você poderá ter livre acesso aos dados armazenados no outro servidor, mas o importante é que o usuário que será utilizado para criar o linked tenha permissão de acesso para trabalhar com estes dados

Exemplo Servidor1, instâcia "192.168.0.10" e o Servidor2, instância "192.168.0.11", e terá que acessar a tabela "Cliente" do servidor final 11, então faça um Linked Server, pode ser pelo Studio mesmo, depois a query será feita da forma abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM [192.168.0.11].[NOME_BANCO].DBO.Cliente
```

Se no linked server você criou utilizando IP será feito da forma acima, porém se fez utilizando a instância, troque o IP pelo nome da instância do SQLSERVER.